# MvcRazorToPdf alternating table row styles

Tags: css, css-selectors, itext, mvcrazortopdf

I have a table that shows and hides certain rows based on some data, so I was hoping to do the row style with CSS, a la:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#fff; }
```

However, it seems MvcRazorToPdf can't apply these styles correctly to a table. Does anyone know how this can be done or why it won't work with MvcRazorToPdf?

Comment: Strange. iTextSharp seems to support it AFAIK, which is what MvcRazorToPdf uses internally. But I can't comment further.

Comment: AFAIK, Razor uses an unofficial, unsupported, unpaid version of iTextSharp, hence nobody at iText Software can comment on the problem you're experiencing.